# dynamic variable inside ngif not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a piece of code like this

```
ng-show="!edit{{id}} && imageUrl"
```

But this does not seem to work. Where as

```
ng-show="!edit1 && imageUrl"
```

works. Is there any problem in syntax??

Actual Piece of code

```
template: '<div id="dropTarget{{imageid}}" ng-show="edit{{imageid}}">'+
            '<img id="imageView{{imageid}}" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />'+
        '</div>'+
        '<img id="imageView{{imageid}}" ng-if="!edit{{imageid}} && imageUrl" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" alt="Coach"/>'+
        '<div class="my-new-photo" ng-if="!edit{{imageid}} && !imageUrl">+</div>'+
        '<span class="edit-info" ng-click="showUploadImageOptions(imageid)" ng-show="!edit{{imageid}} && imageUrl">EDIT</span>'+
        '<span class="edit-info" ng-click="showUploadImageOptions(imageid)" ng-show="!edit{{imageid}} && !imageUrl">NEW</span>'+
            '<div ng-show="edit1" class="buttons-section">'+
                '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
                    '<input type="file" name="filesToUpload{{imageid}}" id="filesToUpload{{imageid}}" style="display:none;"/>'+
                    '<span class="upl-sav-can" ng-click="uploadImage(imageid)">Browse</span>'+
                    '<span  class="upl-sav-can" ng-click="revertImage(imageid)">Cancel</span>'+
                '</form>'+
            '</div>',
```

Comment: Change all `{{ id }}` to `+ 'id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngShow` expects [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) which is *kind of* regular javascript expression (with certain limitations). So think of what you write in these cases, as normal javascript expression.

Now ask yourself: is `!edit{{id}} && imageUrl` valid javascript expression (code)? Of course, no. Angular throws an error when provided expression cannot be parsed and evaluated ([$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service does this) as valid javascript code.

However

```
ng-show="!edit[id] && imageUrl"
```

would be valid expression using bracket notation to access variable property of the object/array. This is what you need to use in this case.

Comment: But its not a array. in JS if i say its like 'edit'+id

Comment: Then it will be `ng-show="!(edit + id) && imageUrl"`.

Comment: @dfsq I want to use this condition in case of form validationlike :- `ng-if="{{formName}}.{{inputFieldName + $index}}.$dirty"`
In this case how should I use dynamic **name** inside `ng-if=""`

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not possible. As @dfsq said, `ngShow` expects Angular expression. You can't access a scope variable by interpolating its name in an Angular expression.

Your best options are to make `edit` an array or an object, and then access it's contents via index or key.

```
ng-show="!edit[id] && imageUrl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the right thing and call a method for that return value?

Partial code:

```
<span class="edit-info" ng-click="showUploadImageOptions(imageid)" ng-show="returnEditId(imageid) && imageUrl">EDIT</span>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.returnEditId = function(id){
        if(!$scope.edit[id])
         return false;
        else
         return true;
    }
```